# Time regularity of traces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations, differential-operators

I have a question about the time regularity of the traces in one dimension.

Suppose I have a function space $$X = C^1([0,T];L^2(0,1))\cap C([0,T],H^1(0,1))$$ and I define an operator $E$ on $X$ by $(Ef)(t) = f(0,t).$ I know that $E$ maps $X$ to $C([0,T]).$

What can we say about $\partial_t Ef$? Where would that function live? What would be the minimal conditions on $X$ so I would have $Ef \in C^1([0,T])$.

Comment: In "$f(0,t)$" where do the 0 and $t$ live? In $[0,T]$ and $(0,1)$? Which is which?

Comment: I am using $t$ for the time variable and $x$ for the space variable. Then since $H^1(0,1)$ embeds into $C([0,1])$ I defining $f(0,t)$ (the trace), so $0 \in [0,1]$ and $t \in [0,T].$ Thanks for the help :)